# Odata v4 error "Does not support untyped value in non-open type"

Tags: rest, odata, httprequest

As I updated the model, it throws "Does not support untyped value in non-open type". It was working before the update. Unable to pin down the source of the problem.
any ideas.

Comment: Would you please describe more detail about your problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've experienced this error before and it's caused by passing a property of a JSON object that doesn't exist on the data model.

For example, given the data model:

```cs
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And an OData controller has the method:

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Post(User user)
```

When the following data is sent using the `POST` method:

```json
{
    "UserId": "0",
    "UserName": "test",
    "UserPassword": "test"
}
```

Then the server will return error 400 with the following response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request is invalid.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "user : Does not support untyped value in non-open type.\r\n",
            "type": "",
            "stacktrace": ""
        }
    }
}
```

So if the `UserPassword` property, in this example, is removed from the data sent using the `POST` method, then the error doesn't occur.

Comment: That makes sense, had to go through a list of properties and figured out a similar reason. thanks Rami,

Comment: Is there any ways to tell oData to ignore additionnal json property of the object ? I need some additional data in my post that are not mapped to DB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Toodoo, in your case, you can try to create and use an open type, like the error message indicates.

Comment: @RamiA.Thanks for your anwser, but I also tried open type, but get some error when using GET...