# POST-ing a new entity to a Web.API OData endpoint without an ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, odata

I'm building a proof-of-concept API using ASP.NET Core 2.1, Web.API, and OData (7.0.0-beta4).

One of my OData endpoints is responsible for basic CRUD operations on an `Employer` entity.  The `POST` endpoint - which creates a brand new `Employer` record - is defined like this:

```
// POST: api/Employers
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostEmployer([FromBody] Employer employer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    _context.Employers.Add(employer);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetEmployer", new { id = employer.Id }, employer);
}
```

My `Employer` entity is defined like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Employer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I hit this OData endpoint with a `POST` body like this:

```
{
    "Name": "My Employer",
    "IsActive": true
}
```

I get an error message:

```
InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
```

This is because the `Id` property is required, but is not provided in my JSON.  However, I don't want to provide the `Id` property, because this property will be auto-generated by the database.  If I *do* provide the `Id` property, my request is successfully routed, but I get an Entity Framework error later in the process (`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column`), which makes sense.

How can I make my OData endpoint ignore the required `Id` property during a `POST` request?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes to your Employer model:

```
[DataContract]
public class Employer
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Id", IsRequired=false, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

More info on DataMemberAttribute properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I gave it a try, and now the routing works as expected - but unfortunately my `ModelState` is flagged as invalid, with the error message `Does not support untyped value in non-open type.`.  As a result, the `employer` variable is `null`.

Comment: The Id property will need to be a nullable Integer: `public int? Id`

Comment: I've tried it both ways - (with the `Id` property nullable and non-nullable), but no luck - I get the same error message.

Comment: That error seems to be caused when there is a property in the JSON that is POSTed to the server that does not exist in the model (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948893/odata-v4-error-does-not-support-untyped-value-in-non-open-type).  Could you double check your JSON input for extra properties?  I am assuming you posted a simplified Employer class / JSON as I don't see any issue with the JSON example posted.  Not sure what else it could be.

Comment: Thanks for the help - it turned out to be unrelated to the entity class (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - it turns out the issue had nothing to do with the `Id` property in my entity class.  Instead, the problem was this line:

```
return CreatedAtAction("GetEmployer", new { id = employer.Id }, employer);
```

The framework must do some kind of validation on the specified action ("GetEmployer"), and it was throwing an error that this action is invalid.

I'm not sure how to correct this string value, but I can avoid the issue altogether by using a simpler return value:

```
return Ok(new { Id = employer.Id });
```